# IAP Issue in testing APK on Mobile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I used the test IAP Id of android.test.purchased in IAP catalog .IAP working correctly on system but On mobile it shows white screen on pop-up by purchase button press.

[image]

[image]

I AM expecting for solution of this problem that i face of IAP issue on testing mobile